# TypeError for classy_enum after upgrading Rails from 3.0.1 to 3.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've just upgraded rails on my development mac from 3.0.1 to 3.0.7.
Tried to run rspec (2.6.0) (with factory_girl_rails 1.0.1) and got errors in all tests where models use classy_enum (0.9.1) gem for status implementation. Rails itself runs without problems, but rspec tests fails. Have no idea what causes the error.

The exact error here:

```
1) Billboard should create a new instance given valid attributes
      Failure/Error: @etype = Factory(:etype)
      TypeError:
          Cannot visit EtypeGroupActivity
   # ./spec/models/billboard_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Etype model code:

```
class Etype < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :group, :order, :logo
  classy_enum_attr :group, :enum => :etype_group
  delegate :group_name, :to => :group
```

Etype_group enum code:

```
class EtypeGroup < ClassyEnum::Base
  enum_classes :event, :event_session, :activity, :venue, :venue_space
  def group_name
    ""
  end
end

class EtypeGroupEvent < EtypeGroup
  def group_name
    I18n.t('etypes.groups.event')
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

The billboard_spec code is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Billboard do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @etype = Factory(:etype)
    @attr = { :title    => "First Keynote",
              :etype_id => @etype,
              :summary  => "This keynote will open our event" }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    @user.billboards.create!(@attr)
  end
end
```

And in factories.db i have:

```
Factory.define :etype do |etype|
  etype.code                 "keynote"
  etype.group                "activity"
  etype.order                10
end
```

Comment: Just replied to your [github issue](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum/issues/3), but could you post some of the billboard_spec here?

Comment: Thanks, i've updated initial posting here

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved as of ClassyEnum [version 1.0.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/classy_enum/versions/1.0.0)